# Need to Check and update the row based on particular column in csv using Shell

Tags: shell, csv

I need to change the value of the csv based on the column,

**csv1:**

```
Account User login status    
guh     guhan 1     upload   
nav     Naveen 2    complete
```

**csv2:**

```
Account User login status     
guh     guhan 1     complete    
nav     Naveen 2    complete
```

**Output csv:**

```
guh     guhan 1     complete    
nav     Naveen 2    complete
```

Need to check from the second line of the line because first line is header of the csv.

```
while IFS="," read Account User login status    
if [ $status in csv1 = $status in csv2 ]    
dont change     
if [$ status in csv1 != $staus in csv2 ] 
change the status value
```

Kindly help me out on this

Comment: It is unclear what status you are changing. Also search this site for "bash read from multiple file descriptors" and you will find several answers already.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what porcessing of your input fiels you want to achieve (Merging?) Also, the files don't look like CSV files at all (there are no commas), but if anything then "space-separated-value" files. Are your files CSV files or space-separated-value" files?

Comment: I need to change the status column in the csv, Need to compare the status column in both csv file and update the change in the output csv

Comment: @halloleo its comma separated only not space

Comment: I need to to compare the status column in both csv and update the data in another csv

Comment: Currently the output is (apart from the header) the same as csv2. Please update your question with a record in csv1 not found in csv2 (and show fields with commas).

Answer (score 0):

If you accept a solution in Python, here you are:

Given `csv1.csv` as

```
Account,User,login,status
guh,guhan,1,upload
nav,Naveen,2,complete
```

and `csv2.csv` as

```
Account,User,login,status
guh,guhan,1,complete
nav,Naveen,2,complete
```

you can run the following script `output.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Update status information from csv1 according to csv2

import csv

with open('csv1.csv') as cf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(cf)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
    rows1 = [ r for r in reader ]
with open('csv2.csv') as cf:
    rows2 = [ r for r in csv.DictReader(cf) ]

KEY_FIELDS = ['Account','User','login']
FIELD_TO_UPDATE = 'status'
OVERWRITE_STATUS = 'complete'

with open('output.csv','w') as cf:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(cf, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for r1 in rows1:
        r_new = r1
        for r2 in rows2:
            if all([ r1[f] == r2[f] for f in KEY_FIELDS ]):
                if r2[FIELD_TO_UPDATE] == OVERWRITE_STATUS:
                    r_new[FIELD_TO_UPDATE] = OVERWRITE_STATUS
        writer.writerow(r_new)
```

This will give you a file `output.py`:

```
Account,User,login,status
guh,guhan,1,complete
nav,Naveen,2,complete
```

Caveat: This script is *very* basic and doesn't scale to large files `csv1.csv` and `csv2.csv`.